# Gray screen on c++ opencv

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have searched a lot about my simple problem but I didn't find solution. When I run my code black console shows me the camera frame size but in the window video is not showing, it shows a solid gray screen. But if I play a video from HDD then it works fine.
Please help me some one.
This is my code

```
  #include <iostream>

#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    CvCapture *capture;
    IplImage* img=0;
    cvNamedWindow("Window");
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( -1);
    //capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("1.mp4");
    //capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);

    int ext=0;

    assert( capture );


    if(capture==NULL){
        cout<<"Cam Not Found!!!"<<endl;
        getchar();
        return -5;
    }
    while ( true ){

        img = cvQueryFrame( capture );

        cvSaveImage("1.jpg",img);

        if (!img){
            printf("Image not Found\n");
            break;
        }


        cvShowImage("Window", img);
        cvWaitKey(50);
    }
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Window");
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

    return 0;
}
```

I use opencv 2.2 and Visual studio 2010

Comment: Whats the output on the black screen? Insert a getchar() method below the output in the 'if(!capture)' and check the output on the black screen.

Comment: I did that but it remain same.

Comment: Output on the black screen? Nothing? You have a webcam?

Comment: In the black box jast showing the message "Size of camera frame: 640 x 480 pixels."
WebCam: Hp ProBook 4430s fixed camera.
OS: Win 7(32bit)

Comment: Try this capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( -1 ); or capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );

Comment: You should swap `cv::waitKey(20)` and `cvShowImage("Window", img)`. Is "Size of camera frame..." printed more than one time?

Comment: Or try capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried all of those idea but it not working...

Comment: @ShamsulArefin, Have you checked the value of capture? Is it NULL?

Comment: @Siddiqui No boss its not NULL..

Comment: Its working fine on my computer! Without any edits, just copied your code!

Comment: @ShamsulArefin boss, output on windows cmd please!

Comment: I update my webcam driver, and try a lot of idea but failed.
I relay don't know whats the problem.
I am very new in opencv.

Comment: boss i have not enough reputation to upload image.
My web cam light is open so its working fine. I used to use this webcam in skype. So its status is good..

Comment: @Banthar Boss i swaped that two statement. And size of camera is printing unlimited time in while(1) loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I jast switch the openCV version 2.2 to 2.1 and its work perfectly.......

Answer (score 2):

One thing is obviouslly wrong, you need to change the order of the calls to:

```
cvShowImage("Window", img);
cv::waitKey(20);
```

Second, it's essential that you check the success of `cvQueryFrame()`:

```
img = cvQueryFrame( capture );
if (!img)
{
    // print something
    break;
}
```

**EDIT:**

By the way, I just noticed you are mixing the C interface of OpenCV with the C++ interface. Don't do that! Replace `cv::waitKey(50);` by `cvWaitKey(50);`.

For debugging purposes, if `cvQueryFrame()` succeeds I suggest you store one frame to the disk with `cvSaveImage()`, and if that image is OK it means the capture procedure is actually working perfectly and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I change my code. When i save a image using cvSaveImage() its a solid gray image.
Not working at all.

Comment: Boss can i use opencv 2.4 for solving my problem?
I think 2.2 is old and not suporting my camera.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Try replacing `cv::waitKey()` for `cvWaitKey()`, and please go ahead and update your OpenCV to 2.4 or newer versions.

Comment: Boss I hope I have to change my camera.
I am facing same problem in opencv 2.4.
and i change cvWaitKey() still same problem.

Comment: Yep, you need to test other cameras to make sure it's not a problem with your code.

Comment: Boss i found a video on youtube which include a **Visual Control** program. That program is made using opencv and msvc 2010. That program using my webcam perfectly. So why i can't using my webcam in my program. Here is the link [You Tube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFSPnu6_TZY) Please advice me. On that link source code is also available.
Thanks.

Comment: In that case, check the source code of the application and copy the camera setup procedure (and the parameters used) to your application.

Comment: You can find me on LinkedIn. Check my profile page on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am using OpenCV version 3.1, I got the same problem, I re-built openCV 3.1 and re-checked Environment Variables, so my problem resolved. You can back-up built-opencv and extract if you need. Sorry for my bad english :)